# What exact dependencies does Ruby need on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

When reading how to install Ruby on Ubuntu, I frequently see this kind of thing:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

But which of these packages are actually needed and which are nice to have?

And also... why?

I can't seem to find any good information online that answers this question.

Comment: Just depends on what you need. APT normally resolves dependencies automatically.

Comment: You can google each of the dependencies to see what they do, but this really isn't bloatware and it's probably easier to just install them

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that. How is it not bloatware if it's not needed?

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache showpkg <specific-ruby-version-package>` will show you the package dependencies.  As above comment says, `apt-get install ...` will automatically install the dependencies.  Anything people are installing  beyond that may have to do with their development environment or the ability to build specific gems with native extensions.

Comment: Is there a minimum required set of dependencies that are the rule of thumb? What are they and why are they needed?